# Protractor No element found using locator: by.buttonText

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor

Running a simple end to test using protractor, load a page, click on a button and the navigate to the next page after clicking the button but i'm getting the following error
    No element found using locator: by.buttonText(Register as a Buyer)
This is the HTML behind the button

```html
<a href="/register/buyer" class="btn" data-ss1491391037="1">
                    Register as a Buyer</a>
```

And snippet from my protractor file

```js
element(by.buttonText("Register as a Buyer")).click();
```

Not sure what I'm missing here or what I'm supposed to change, I'm brand new to Protractor.
I was able to get something similar above to work using a different button, except that button had a value assigned to it in the HTML code whereas the above doesn't.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Please put some wait and try `element(by.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Register as a Buyer')]")).click();`

Comment: Thanks a million, that works

Comment: The above worked for me but it may be helpful for other people who are new to Protractor to post an answer

Comment: Means? I am not getting you

Comment: That's a link, not a button.  So you can't use buttonText...

Answer (score 2):

Like buttons, protractor also has special methods to identify anchor tags based on their text. Try using `by.linkText()` or `by.partialLinkText()`

Answer (score 1):

The element you're trying to click is not a `button`, but rather a link. Thus, `by.buttonText` won't work... you can use one of the following:

```
element(by.cssContainingText('.btn', 'Register as a Buyer')).click();
```

or if you only have one `.btn` link:

```
$('.btn').click();
```

or perhaps you have many buttons but want to click the first one:

```
$$('.btn').first().click();
```